# iOS : Revealing previous and next page boundries in pageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

As i m new to iOS and swift. I was trying with pageViewcontroller having a view with multiple pages. I want edges of previous and next pages to be shown. you can refer the Url of the image below

https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/02/4e/82/024e82fc4d3c7f8116ae33cea87b69f3.jpg

i tried by giving the Page Spacing in the PageViewController but it's not working.

Please help me out of this. Thanks in Advance